# Can we replace swagger-ui with redoc in Springdoc

Tags: springdoc

I'm trying to replace a manually-maintained swagger file with Springdoc. Currently, we use [ReDoc](https://github.com/Redocly/redoc) to render the file, because of their support for `discriminator`.

Is there a straightforward way to replace/supersede the embedded `swagger-ui` with `ReDoc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In springdoc you can skip using the swagger UI package and use:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

instead. Then you can point to the location of swagger schema generated with springdoc (default is /v3/api-docs) in your `<redoc />` component. The rest is depending on how you host Redoc. In our case we just added a controller to our service/app that serves a basic HTML described on Redoc documentation page (https://github.com/Redocly/redoc#tldr).

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the default swagger-ui with

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.enabled=false
```

see the "Disabling the swagger-ui" section at https://springdoc.org/

After that, all you need to do is put ReDoc on your server and have it point to the OpenAPI description usually at /context-path/v3/api-docs
See the "Deployment" section at https://github.com/Redocly/redoc